# Poppulate array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm creating a deck of cards. Cards are structures

```
 struct card{
    char* suit;
    char* face;
 };
```

and the deck will just be an array of card structs.

```
for(s = 0; s < sizeof(SUITS); s++){
    for(f = 0; f < sizeof(FACE); f++){

    thisCard.suit = SUITS[s];
    thisCard.face = FACE[f];
    deck[cardNum]=thisCard;
    cardNum++;
}
```

suits and face are arrays with all suits and arrays

```
const char* SUITS[] = {"Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts"};

const char* FACE[] = {"ACE", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR","FIVE",
 "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING"};
```

and then I print out the deck with this format **face** of **suit**

```
for(cardNum= 0; cardNum < DECKSIZE; cardNum++){
    thisCard = deck[cardNum];
    printf("%s of %s \n",thisCard.face,thisCard.suit);      
}
```

So I have lots of problems here. Im not sure if the way im making the array will work. It appears that Im not cycling through the suits when I do this. I know it compiles with a warning since im using a const string for my regular struct thing. But im not sure why it doesnt work well.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this site is designed for solving specific well explained problems. You have not provided a Minimal complete verifiable Example or the actual errors you are encountering so it will be very difficult for people to give you good answers. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know it isn't your question, but I can't help it: I'd try to avoid the unnecessary struct copies via not using `thisCard` and writing straight into the deck `deck[cardNum].suit = SUITS[s]; deck[cardNum].face = FACE[f];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof(SUITS)` gives you the size of `SUITS` in *bytes*. Your loop, on the other hand, need the number of entries in `SUITS`, not the number of bytes. The common trick for computing the count of array elements is dividing `sizeof(SUITS)` by `sizeof(SUITS[0])`:

```
for(s = 0; s < sizeof(SUITS)/sizeof(SUITS[0]); s++) {
    for(f = 0; f < sizeof(FACE)/sizeof(FACE[0]); f++) {
        deck[cardNum].suit = SUITS[s];
        deck[cardNum].face = FACE[f];
        cardNum++;
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/1nIBhT)

Comment: This worked but now it gives me a bunch of random characters and a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you so much. I realized the issue. I had ONE and ACE in my face array. I fixed it and it is all working fine now.